# MySql Transaction/Statement Count

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to figure out how to count the number of transactions/statements executed against a MySql database on a given interval.

**Has anyone done this before?**

**Are there any mysql tables that track these metrics?**

I know SQL Server tracks this sort of thing, but I haven't been able to find anything for mysql.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G

...
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 34824
...
```

The transaction id counter is incremented for every transaction involving an InnoDB table.

If your statement does not touch an InnoDB table, the number is not incremented. But [you should be using InnoDB anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/).

In MySQL 5.6, there's also the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_METRICS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-metrics-table.html) table, but it does not collect data by default -- you have to turn on each counter specifically (see documentation for details).